# Insert Trigger mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 2 tables, the first one has columns (Id,Siteid,Article_link), the second (Id,Sitename), I want the siteid column to be inserted automatically when inserting into the first table, for example, if in the second table
there is a filled line (3,https://stackoverflow.com/) when I add to the first one (1,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) I want the siteid to be immediately set to 3 in the first table

Im trying write trigger like this:

```
AFTER INSERT ON links FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE links SET siteid=id WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM sites) and link REGEXP(SELECT sitename FROM sites);
```

But I can't access the table I'm inserting data into

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA2Gd.png) Table Links

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRVlR.png) What i wanna

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiiZZ.png) Table Sites

Comment: You cannot update the table which the trigger is defined on. Edit values in NEW pseudotable instead.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: @Akina I know, But how can I automate what I want to implement so that the insertion into the siteid column is done automatically

Comment: Read the article by provided link and add complete example into your question.

Comment: *if in the second table there is a filled line `(3,https://stackoverflow.com/)` when I add to the first one `(1,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)`* In theory - it is possible that more than one row in Sites table matches the links which are inserted into Links table. You must avoid this with according constraint in Sites table - think about it.

Comment: I've added screenshots of what I want to end up with.
@Akina

Comment: O_O Does the article tells that the images are applicable? Only well-formatted text **which can be copypasted** is safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### DEMO

```
CREATE TABLE sites (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  sitename VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (sitename)
  );
CREATE TABLE links (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  siteid INT,
  article_link VARCHAR(2048),
  FOREIGN KEY (siteid) REFERENCES sites (id)
  );
```

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_siteid
BEFORE INSERT ON links
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.siteid = (
  SELECT id
  FROM sites
  WHERE NEW.article_link LIKE CONCAT(sites.sitename, '%')
  );
```

```
INSERT INTO sites (sitename) VALUES 
  ('http://stackoverflow.com/'),
  ('http://mail.google.com/'),
  ('http://dba.stackoverflow.com/'),
  ('https://google.com/'),
  ('https://mail.google.com/');
```

```
INSERT INTO links (article_link) VALUES
  ('https://google.com/search?text=something'),
  ('http://mail.google.com/message=123.html'),
  ('http://stackoverflow.com/main.htm'),
  ('http://google.com/rules/main.html');
```

```
SELECT * FROM sites;
SELECT * FROM links;
```

| id | sitename |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | http://dba.stackoverflow.com/ |
| 2 | http://mail.google.com/ |
| 1 | http://stackoverflow.com/ |
| 4 | https://google.com/ |
| 5 | https://mail.google.com/ |

| id | siteid | article_link |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | https://google.com/search?text=something |
| 2 | 2 | http://mail.google.com/message=123.html |
| 3 | 1 | http://stackoverflow.com/main.htm |
| 4 | *null* | http://google.com/rules/main.html |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/T4ly0TxK)